# TabulatorJS 4.5 Find table func: In combination with deleteRow() not working

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Hi Tabulator community,

We recently upgraded from Tabulator.js version 4.4 to 4.5 to get access to new Find Tables functionality (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/options#find-table) because we need to get access to TabulatorJS tables from separate JSPs.
Beside that we are using jquery_wrapper.min.js.

We are calling following lines of code in a separate JSP:
`var table = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#tabulator_user_Wizard');` to get access to table "tabulator_user_Wizard", which seem to work.
Then we call `table.deleteRow(5);` (the table has more than 5 rows)
But this call is not working. After this call no other lines of code in the Javascript are executed.

Also not working is:

```js
var row = table.getRow(5);
row.delete();
```

Do you know why? Is this because of `jquery_wrapper.min.js`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because calling `table.deleteRow(5)` is not asking tabulator to delete the 5th row. it is asking it to find a row with an ***id*** property in its data object with a value of 5 and then delete it.

Have a look a the [Component Lookup Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/components#lookup) to see the list of valid options to pass into this function

In this case the correct approach would be to get the row at position 5 then call the delete function on it:

```
table.getRowFromPosition(5).delete();
```